# Dynamically adding participants to state in Corda 4.0

Tags: blockchain, corda

Can participants be dynamically added to state inside a flow so that state will be stored in thirdParty vault without  using StatesToRecord.ALL_VISIBLE in ReceiveFinalityFlow?

We have done same thing in Corda 2.0, it is not working in Corda 4.0.

Is it not supported in Corda 3.2 onwards? I see @KeepForDJVM is added to ContractState.

I tried to add participants dynamically in IOUState as `[iouState.participants.add(thirdParty)]` after participants in IOUState is updated as mutableList as `[override val participants: MutableList<AbstractParty> = mutableListOf(lender, borrower)]` so that IOUState will be stored in ThirdParty vault as well. I am passing flow sessions of both borrower and thirdParty to CollectSigntaureFlow and FinalityFlow as well. IOUFlowTests `[flow records the correct IOU in both parties' vaults]` is failed with iouState is not found in thridParty vault.

```
IOUState:
@BelongsToContract(IOUContract::class)
data class IOUState(val value: Int,
                    val lender: Party,
                    val borrower: Party,
                    val thirdParty: Party,
                    override val linearId: UniqueIdentifier = UniqueIdentifier()):
        LinearState, QueryableState {
    /** The public keys of the involved parties. */
    //override val participants: MutableList<AbstractParty> get() = mutableListOf(lender, borrower)
    override val participants = mutableListOf(lender, borrower)


ExampleFlow:
var iouState = IOUState(iouValue, serviceHub.myInfo.legalIdentities.first(), otherParty, thirdParty)

iouState.participants.add(thirdParty)

val txCommand = Command(IOUContract.Commands.Create(), iouState.participants.map { it.owningKey })

val counterparties = iouState.participants.map { it as Party }.filter { it.owningKey != ourIdentity.owningKey }.toSet()

counterparties.forEach { p -> flowSessions.add(initiateFlow(p))}

val fullySignedTx = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(partSignedTx, flowSessions, GATHERING_SIGS.childProgressTracker()))

            // Stage 5.
            progressTracker.currentStep = FINALISING_TRANSACTION
            // Notarise and record the transaction in both parties' vaults.
            return subFlow(FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx, flowSessions, FINALISING_TRANSACTION.childProgressTracker()))
```

Both Counterparties Borrower and ThirdParty receives flow and sign transaction, but does not see thirdParty in Participants list and not stored in ThirdParty vault.

I am expecting ThirdParty should be in Participants list and IOUState should be stored in ThirdParty Vault as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Corda, states are immutable. This means that you cannot dynamically add participants to a given state in the body of a flow. There are other solutions, however, to informing a new third party of the state!

There are two ways to accomplish your goals here:

1. Create a new IOUState tx output with an updated participant list.

In the body of the flow, you should create a new IOUState with an updated list of participants. You will have to update the IOUState so that `participants` is a value in the primary constructure. Then you might use a helper method like this to add a participant:

```
fun addParticipant(partyToAdd: Party): IOUState = copy(participants + partyToAdd)
```

Here's the important part: you must then include the old IOUState as an input to this transaction and the new IOUState as an output. Corda is based on the UTXO model - the only way to update a state is to mark it as history (use it as an input) and then persist an updated version to the ledger.

Note: as a participant, the informed party will now be able to propose changes to this IOUState - these must be accounted for in the Corda Contract.

2. Use the SendStateAndRefFlow (Likely the better solution for your issue)

The SendStateAndRefFlow will (as specified in its name) send a state and its associated stateRef to the receiving node. The counterparty (receiving node) must use `ReceiveStateAndRefFlow` at the correct point in the flow conversation.

```
subFlow(new SendStateAndRefFlow(counterpartySession, dummyStates));
```

Both of these methods will cause the receiving node to validate the dependencies of the state (all of the inputs and transactions that comprise its history)

Comment: Thanks Nick for your response, I tried to add copy method as you mentioned, but participants from ContractState is not visible inside copy method. It gives compile error. We followed the way you mentioned in point #1. Since it is MutableList, we are able to add participant in a flow, it worked in Corda 2.0, but not working in Corda 4.0

Comment: It is working now after participants property is added to Constructor instead of body.

Comment: if override val participants = mutableListOf(lender, borrower) is moved to constructor then we will be able copy IOUState with thirdParty and working fine.

Comment: @Muthu - excellent! Glad it worked. To be completely candid I have less experience in Corda 2.0 but I know that you need to produce a new state with an updated list of participants to effect change in distribution.

Comment: Did this solve your issue? Should I edit my answer with more info?

Comment: Thanks @Muthu - would you mind clicking the checkmark to indicate the question was answered?